# What is the recommended approach to use PHP session objects on a high traffic site?

Tags: php, session

I am currently working on a website that has high traffic by my standards. It's a webshop and has a few (serialized) objects in it's session.

E.g.

```
$_SESSION['shoppingcart'] = new Shoppingcart();
```

And this object is later used throughout the code. So far no problem.
The session duration is 1 hour at the moment and is extended when users keep it alive by making requests.

Now for the (probably well known) problem: When making a change to the `Shoppingcart` class in the example there is a chance that the change breaks the deserializing of the object. What can we do to prevent this problem? What is the recommended approach?

- We can keep values in the database and only use a primitive int inside the session to identify the primary key.
- We can use some array conversion from the object.
- ?

Comment: Yes and yes. If you change something about a data structure, there's always the problem of migrating existing records. In the case of ephemeral sessions, you may simply choose to discard them when the structure doesn't match. If such sessions are important enough for you to preserve at all costs, use a storage mechanism that can be migrated.

Comment: "We can keep values in the database and only use a primitive int inside the session to identify the primary key." is the right answer. If you want to avoid taxing your database on every page load then you can also store a `cart_item_count` directly in the DB and display that next to your cart icon. When the user actually opens/views their cart then load the full details.

Comment: If you want to really, really use your object then you can try and build in some portability into `Shoppingcart` by extending the [`Serializable class`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php#example-327) so that you are only serializing a piece of the object instead of the whole thing. You will have to build error-checking into the `unserialize()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good chance there is an expert here that has a better answer, but for now I will share what I found.

> Given all these potential problems, I strongly advise against storing
>   objects in the session. If you want to persist the logged in user,
>   instead of storing an instance of a User class in $_SESSION, just
>   store the user ID and populate the user object from the database or
>   cache. It’s a little more work than letting PHP magically handle
>   everything for you, but your application will be much more stable and
>   portable without object serialization.

**source**: https://www.phparch.com/2018/01/php-sessions-in-depth/